# Handling a Bownian motion inside a r.v.

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

I'm studying Brownian motion and stopping time and I struggle when it comes to mix both. I know that $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion and $(Y_t) = 3 + B_{2t}$.

I understand that $(Y_t)$ is not a martingale w.r.t. the natural filtration of $(B_{2t})$ because it is not measurable with w.r.t. the information available at time $T$, it is observed only at time $2t$.

I don't understand how I need to use the exit time of a brownian motion starting from $0$ out of a bond $(-a,b)$ including Doob's optional stopping to T^n to find $P(Y_T =7)$ after translation from 0 to 3. I only know that the answer is $1/3$

Comment: What is $T$? $ $

Comment: Sorry. That's the chosen stopping time.

Comment: **Which stopping time?**

Comment: At which the process goes out of the bond (-a,b)

Comment: Please make your post fully self-contained (and, even before that, simply *understandable*). One should not have to pester you like I just did, just to extract crucial information from you.